# In my javascript, how can I fix this encoding issue between "\u0026", "&amp;" and "&"?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, encoding, javascriptserializer

I have an asp.net-mvc website and I have the following code in one of my views:

```
var teams = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.Names) %>;
```

**Model.Names** is a string array and one of the names, a team has a name "Joe & Bob" and it shows up in the html as:

```
 "Joe \u0026 Bob"
```

even though it displays as "Joe & Bob" in the browser

The issue is that I have another line of code that tries to do a compare against "Joe & Bob" and it can't find it.  When i looked into it the code  on why its failing its simply spitting out a variable like this

```
 "<%= Model.Name %>",
```

and in the browser source I see

```
"Joe & Bob"
```

(instead of Joe \u0026 Bob)

I tried doing this

```
   <%=Html.Encode(Model.Name); %>
```

so I can do a proper comparison but I got:

```
 Joe &amp; Bob
```

instead of Joe \u0026 Bob

I wanted to get some advice for the cleanest way to get the same exact string in the browser source so I could do a proper comparison.

Comment: How does your other line of code try to do a compare against "Joe & Bob". Chances are, that's where the problem lies.

Comment: agree but that is inside a jquery plugin so i am trying to make sure my inputs are perfectly consistent to avoid any possibility for the plugin to "get it wrong"

Comment: Even if it's inside the plugin, I'd like to see how it's doing the comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript "\u0026" is totally equivalent to "&", so if you were doing a javascript comparison this would work fine:

```
console.log("Joe \u0026 Bob" == "Joe & Bob"); // true
```

But if you want to represent this string in text, you definitely want it to be HTML-encoded into `&amp;` instead.

```
<span class="name"><%=Html.Encode(Model.Name)%></name>
```

If you do this, then the text value of the DOM element should still be "Joe & Bob" as far as JavaScript is concerned:

```
console.log($('.name').text()); // "Joe & Bob"
console.log($('.name').text() == "Joe & Bob"); // true
console.log($('.name').text() == "Joe \u0026 Bob"); // true
```

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I think the root cause is how a jquery plugin is treating that so i am trying to remove any possibility of this being different strings.  In C#, how can I convert '\u0026' to '&'?

Comment: @leora: Have you considered using JSON.NET to serialize your json? It doesn't try to convert values like "&" to unicode codes. Still, it's difficult for me to understand how the jQuery plugin could possibly see this the wrong way, since the in-memory string in JavaScript will have exactly the same value.

Comment: turns out the whole encoding thing was a complete red herring . . the root issue was completely unrelated :( .. thanks for the help anyway.  I will accept your answer

Comment: @leora: I thought that might be the case. Good luck.